# Asymptotic Likelihood of a sequence in an ergodic markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider a sequence of $N$ transitions on an ergodic markov chain with $n$ states. Show that as $N\rightarrow \infty$:

$$1/N \log p_{:N} \rightarrow^{a.s.} H$$

Where $p_{:N}$ is the likelihood of a sequence of length $N$ and $H$ is the entropy of the markov chain:

$$H = -\sum_{i, j} P_i p_{j|i} \log p_{j|i}$$

Where $P_i$ is the marginal probability of being in state $i$ and $p_{j|i}$ is the transition probability to state $j$ from state $i$.

Recall that in a markov chain, the transition probabilities are only dependent on the current state (and independent of the past given the current state). In an ergodic markov chain, time averages converge to ensemble averages almost surely.

**What I've tried**

The probability of a given sequence can be factored as the probability of reaching the $N-1$th state then making the $N$th transition:

$$p_{:N} = p_{:N-1}p_{k|l}$$

Where $p_{k|l}$ is the transition probability from the $N-1$th state to the $N$th state.

Iterating this relation we get:

$$p_{:N} = p_{1}\prod_{i=1}^{N-1}p_{i+1|i}$$

The proof I'm following does not proceed with such a factorization, instead they go directly to considering the likelihood as a multinomial:

$$p_{:N} = \prod_{i,j}p_{j|i}^{m_{j|i}}$$

where $m_{j|i}$ is the number of times the transition from state $i$ to $j$ occurred in the sequence of length $N$. They then argue that by the strong law of large numbers, this converges a.s. to $P_ip_{j|i}N$. Taking logarithms and rearranging yields the claim.

My confusion is: how do I justify their expression of $p_{:N}$? I understand that intuitively it makes sense, since time averages converge a.s. to ensemble averages, but I feel there is something missing from the argument. In particular, I am looking for some argument to go from the finite case (specified in my factorization of $p_{:N}$) to the asymptotic case.

See appendix 3 from [1] for the proof that I am confused about. The statement of the theorem is on page 13 (theorem 3).

#### References

[1] Shannon, Claude Elwood. "A mathematical theory of communication." ACM SIGMOBILE mobile computing and communications review 5.1 (2001): 3-55.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p_{:N}$ can be rewritten as:

$$p_{:N} = P_1\prod_{i,j}p_{j|i}^{m_{j|i}}$$

So all that remains to show is that for large enough $N$, the contribution from $P_1$ is negligible:

$$1/N \log p_{:N} = 1/N\log P_1 + \sum_{i,j} m_{j|i}\log p_{j|i}$$

$1/N\log P_1$ converges to $0$ a.s. Now the rest of the argument goes through without modification.

See the proof of theorem 4.5 in [2]

#### References

[2] LeBlanc, Patrick. "Information Theory: Entropy, Markov Chains, and Huffman Coding."